# Get page number with javascript modulus

Tags: modulus

I have the following figures to work with:

```
totalItems = 26;
itemsPerPage = 6;
currentItem = 17;

currentPage = ??
```

Given those figures (or any current item value), how can I determine what the current page is. I think I need to use the modulus function but I can't fathom out which way to go about it.

Could anyone help please? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the [`ceil`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) function

```
//In javascript
currentPage=Math.ceil(currentItem/itemsPerPage);//=3
//17/6=2.8333.. ceiling (round up to nearest integer) = 3
```

It's worth pointing out this is assuming 1 based paging (first page is page 1 not page 0) and 1 based item number (meaning page 1 has items 1-6, page 2 has items 7-12).

Comment: whats the different if its 0 based paging and 0 based items? meaning items are `0 - n` and paging is `0 - n`